# Avoid Husky from being triggered for changes on every unrelated directory in monorepo project

Tags: yarnpkg, lerna, husky

I'm using husky in my lerna monorepo project which has more than one directory (project)

```
.husky
front
├── package.json
app
└── package.json
```

on hook `prepush` I launch my test on front/ and app/ with `yarn test`.

I would like to have the test for a folder (project) only when the code inside change. Like github Actions.

```
on:
    paths:
      - 'front/**'
```

do there is a way in Husky ?

Comment: Not in Husky itself, that hooks into git at the repo level, but depending on what you're trying to do it might be possible with whatever's actually running the tests (e.g. Jest can take a list of the files to run the tests for: https://jestjs.io/docs/cli#--findrelatedtests-spaceseparatedlistofsourcefiles.

Comment: I'm trying for all sort of command actually, for linter check on pre-commit as well

Comment: That's exactly what things like `lint-staged` are designed for, they pass a list of the staged files to the commands you supply (which you could use with the above Jest flag, for example). So Husky -> lint-staged -> whatever scripts runs the test/lint/whatever given a list of files.

Answer (score 3):

I found a hack

- I get all the file change in the all commits
- I check for my folders
- And trigger a command contextually

```
// ~/.husky/pre-push

#!/bin/sh
. "$(dirname $0)/_/husky.sh"

declare IS_APP_FOLDER_CHANGE=$(git show --name-only -r --stat --oneline HEAD^^..HEAD | grep 'app/')

echo "IS_APP_FOLDER_CHANGE  --> + $IS_APP_FOLDER_CHANGE"

if [[ $IS_APP_FOLDER_CHANGE ]]; then cd app && yarn test --watchAll=false && cd ..; fi
```

Comment: This, in fact, doesn't grab files in all commits. It grabs files from the last two commits, hence the `HEAD^^..HEAD`

Answer (score 3):

for some reason declare not work on my config

my working example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
. "$(dirname -- "$0")/_/husky.sh"

#run husky pre-commit hook only if frontend changed
if git diff --name-only --cached | grep 'frontend/';
  then
    echo "FRONTEND FOLDER CHANGED --> starting husky..."
    cd frontend/ && quasar test --unit vitest
    yarn lint-staged
    yarn test:e2e:ci
    quasar build;
fi
```

Castro Crea thanks a lot!

Comment: This does exactly what I needed, thanks so much!