# Run Husky hooks only for specific folder changes

Tags: node.js, git, husky, git-husky

Is it possible to run only git hooks for when only files in certain folder are changed??

I have monorepo with backend and frontend. I would like to run husky hook only when the files in frontend got changed. Otherwise it should not be triggered and not run linting tests etc... It's irritating backend developers

Comment: A hook triggers on all commits - but your hook can contain logic to limit what it is inspecting.

Comment: Probably you would love to look at [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76811469/8784518).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

With combination on lint-staged I managed to run husky hooks checks on only desired folder changes.

```
module.exports = {
  '*': (files) => {
    const isAppFolderChanges = files.some((fileName) =>
      fileName.includes('/app/'),
    )
    const scripts = [
      'npm run lint-fix',
      './node_modules/.bin/pretty-quick --staged',
      'npm test',
    ]

    return isAppFolderChanges ? scripts : []
  },
}
```

Comment: Where does this file go? What's it called?